# Firebase data structure - Keeping duplicated data up-to-date

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I created a flatted data structure. When pushing duplicated data whats the accepted pattern for keeping that data up-to-date. Here the data for the groups info is duplicated into the `users-groups` and the `groups` tree.

```
{
 "users": ..
 "users-groups": ..
 "groups": ..
}
```

When creating a group for a user two updates takes place:

First: push to /groups/group_key

```
{
 "name": "Test Group",
 "image: "/testimage.jpg"
}
```

Second: push to /users-groups/user_uid/group_key

```
{
 "orderNum: 0,
 "info": {
  "name": "Test Group",
  "image: "/testimage.jpg"
 }
}
```

Should keeping this data in the user-groups up-to-date be a job for the client or should a server handle this?

The data in the groups tree will always be the newest and the changes should propagate down to all the users that are members of that group.

Is there any tutorials or reference material for this problem?

note: i'm using this structure because a user can be a member of multiple groups and I don't think it would be a good idea to make possibly several `ref.once`'s to get the data from the `/groups/` directly.

Comment: what? this? [Transferring Data Using Sync Adapters](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/index.html)

Comment: No i'm taking about the data structure nothing specific to android

Comment: I think you may be looking for this: firebase.googleblog.com/2015/10/client-side-fan-out-for-data-consistency_73.html

Comment: Thanks man thats exactly it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use multi path update. Just observe reference with function and update all other informations

```
db.ref("").update({
  '/users/dedd': info,
  '/users/cdcd': info2
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not have data saved duplicated. Instead you should save reference to group.

Your data should look like this.

```
{
    "users": {
        "userkey1": {
            "data": {
                "name": "",
                "firstname": ""
            },
            "groups": {
                "groupkey1": true // true or orderNum value
            }
        }
    },
    "groups": {
        "groupkey1": {
            "data": {
                "name": "Test Group",
                "image": "/testimage.jpg",
                "other": "data"
            },
            "users": {
                "userkey1": true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can easily check if user is in group by checking if value at any of these positions is `true`.

`users/userkey1/groups/groupkey1` or `groups/groupkey1/users/userkey1`.

When you create new group you save in under `groups/newgroupkey` position and you updated `groups` under `users` node by only setting `newgroupkey` to `true`.
So you do not duplicate your data.

For more information about structuring your data check the following link.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data

Comment: Yeah thats want i'm going for, though i'm using data duplication as well. Why not use duplicated data? It saves me from having to create listeners for all the "joins"? Data duplication is an accepted pattern in NOSQL right?

Comment: For example, If I want to a pull a list of the users groups then I need to initialize a listener for the users-groups collection and then one or more for each to link to the actual group information.

Comment: Yes maybe you are right. If you need to  fetch all groups with their info duplicates version will perform better, but what if you need users with their info for particular group. In this case you have to duplicate users info also.

Comment: Yeah I know that what I'm debating, just for this this little example i'm going to have to introduce two data fans that need to be maintained. The way I perceive the blog post that Frank van Puffelen referenced is: NOSQL handles that fine. For my instance I think thats going to be because I can limit the number of groups a user can have and the number of users a group can have, so I don't think that will be a problem for me.

Comment: I mentioned the server because if worst comes to worse I could queue fan out tasks on it or something where each client isn't having to maintain fanouts with thousands dependancies.

Comment: I was watching a pluralsight course that stated that you should duplicate your data. This doesn't seem right to me. I would have dumb things the way you have but apparently this is a relational way of thinking and isn't right. I'm still not sure

Comment: ok, so how do you get a list of group data back for a particular user, you would use snapShot.forEach, but that returns you an object not a list, how do i get a list of groups back like the way you call /groups, but for users/userid/groups